# Change bash shell for a shell script

Tags: ssh

I've develop an interactive shell script, where my users will perform a few operations. I've create a user that runs this scripts automatically on startup.

```
Startup script ./.bash_login
-------------------------------
/scripts/interactive_shell.py
exit
```

This script performs correctly my interest, it runs my python interactive script, and when I kill my script, it runs exit and finish my connection.

The security problem appears when I'm connecting using my private key with something like this

```
ssh user@host.com -i security_key '/bin/bash'
```

It runs bash shell and I can get something I don't want control over the machine.

My question is, is it possible to change the shell at /etc/passwd to my script or It's preferable to jailroot this user?

Thanks!

Comment: You know you can tie a particular command to the key by editing the entry in the authorized_keys file ... `command="/scripts/interactive_shell.py" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to change the /etc/passwd file to something like this

```
sec_user1:x:1001:1001:Secure User 1:/home/sec_user1:/scripts/interactive_shell.py
```

It works! and if you try to execute some kind of code I'll get this:

```
option -c not recognized

Usage: console.py [OPTION] [PATHS]
    --name=value    whatever
    --help          display help
```

I soupose this is 100% secure, but it's you cannot run commands easilly.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out rssh (the restricted shell).

Comment: Please explain why you suggest rssh